# SQL XML Access node 'n' in a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, loops, nodes

I have an asynchronous auditing system I wrote for SQL Server, which uses triggers to send a message to a Service Broker queue, which calls a Stored Procedure to process the queue and log the details.

It all works perfectly if a single change (an Update or a Delete) happens, using the following code snippets:-

Get message from queue:

```
DECLARE @Message XML;
RECEIVE TOP(1) @Message = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), message_body) FROM AuditLogReceiveQueue;
```

I then store the name of the field I want to extract into the variable @fieldname

Get the node I want from the XML

```
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[1]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

All well and good, this gets the value I want.

However, it's possible for multiple Inserts nodes to be present, so I need to go through them all.

Accessing the specific Inserts node is simple enough, the following works if there are three (or more)

```
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[1]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[2]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[3]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

Bit hard to see with the narrow code boxes, but if you scroll to the right you'll see the number in square brackets near the end is the node number, [1], [2], [3] etc.

So, logically I just need to have a variable containing the number of Inserts nodes, and loop through it:-

```
DECLARE @nEntries INT = (SELECT @Message.value('count(/Inserts)', 'int'))

SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[sql:variable("@nEntries")]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

@nEntries contains the correct number, so that part works (when tested independently), however with the SET @InsertedValue = line in it won't even let me run the ALTER PROCEDURE script, it falls over with:-

```
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence),
    found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
```

on the SET @InsertedValue =  line

I tried casting the variable as an integer a couple of ways:-

[xs:integer(sql:variable("@nEntries"))]

```
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[xs:integer(sql:variable("@nEntries"))]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

That gives the same error:-

```
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence),
    found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
```

[sql:variable("@nEntries") cast as xs:integer]

```
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[sql:variable("@nEntries") cast as xs:integer]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

That gives:

```
XQuery [value()]: In this version of the server, 'cast as <type>' is not available. 
Please use the 'cast as <type> ?' syntax.
```

[sql:variable("@nEntries") cast as xs:integer ?]

```
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[sql:variable("@nEntries") cast as xs:integer ?]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

That gets me back to

```
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence),
    found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
```

[sql:variable("@nEntries")]  cast as xs:integer ?

```
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[sql:variable("@nEntries")] cast as xs:integer ?', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

This basically lies to me:-

```
XQuery [value()]: Cannot explicitly convert from 'xdt:untypedAtomic *' to 'xs:integer ?'
```

According to:-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/type-casting-rules-in-xquery?view=sql-server-2017

you can cast from untypedAtomic to decimal, and integer is a sub-type of decimal.

So, not sure why it's moaning about that.

I tried without the square brackets: sql:variable("@nEntries")

```
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])sql:variable("@nEntries")', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

That give me

```
XQuery [value()]: No more tokens expected at the end of the XQuery expression. Found 'sql'.
```

I tried with extra square brackets: [[sql:variable("@nEntries")] cast as xs:integer ?]

```
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[[sql:variable("@nEntries")] cast as xs:integer ?]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

That gives

```
XQuery [value()]: Syntax error near '['
```

I knew it wouldn't work, as I'd already discovered this creating the system in the first place, but just to cover all the bases I tried using string concatenation

```
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(Max),@nEntries) + '] cast as xs:integer ?]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

As expected, this gave

```
The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.
```

I also tried using a variable:-

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(Max) = '(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(Max),@nEntries) + '] cast as xs:integer ?]'
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value(@Query, 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

Again

```
The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.
```

And that's the point I decided to beg for help from you fine folks!

Given that I'm using sql:variable quite successfully in the exact same call (the below works fine, but only gets the first Inserts data)...

```
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[1]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

... does anyone have any ideas I've not tried to let me use a sql:variable for the node number?

Edit:

I also tried [sql:variable("@nEntries")[1]], just in case it thought @nEntries could have multiple values

```
SET @InsertedValue = (SELECT @Message.value('(/Inserts/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@fieldname")])[sql:variable("@nEntries")[1]]', 'NVARCHAR(Max)'))
```

Gives our old friend

```
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
```

Workaround Edit:-

I have created a workaround where I create a temporary table, and insert one row with each matching Inserts and Deletes record, and then step through that table. That lets me use [1] as before, which works nicely.

But I'd still like to know how to use a variable as above, for future use!

Comment: That's... a lot. Could you perhaps narrow it down to your actual use case, as in, input and output, instead of all the things that don't work? Right now it's not clear to me if there isn't a solution that doesn't require *any* kind of looping at all, whether based on XML or not. For example, you can use `sql:column` to pluck a value from a column instead, and combine this with `CROSS APPLY` to effectively join between a table and XML (and then loop on *that*, if you still have to, but even that may not be necessary), or use a full FLWOR query. I've never looped by using indexes in XPath.

Comment: Having said all that, if for some reason you *were* reduced to using a variable to index, a workaround is to add `[1]` to the whole expression (`(/...)[sql:variable("@i")][1]`). You *almost* achieved that, but your brackets were wrong. The whole problem is that the XPath compiler disagrees that indexing with a variable is guaranteed to produce a singleton, but you know there's only one node, so just take it. Again, though, I wouldn't use that in production code, because parsing the XML multiple times seems like avoidable overhead.